# What does it mean for the $\textbf{B}$-field (Hypercharge) to be in the 0 representation within the SM?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, notation, representation-theory

I was reading through the wikipedia page for the mathematical formulation of the standard model and I noticed that it listed the representations of the vector bosons under the SM gauge groups as being the following:

| field | Representation under $SU(3)_{C}\times SU(2)_{L} \times U(1)_{Y}$ |
| --- | --- |
| B | ($\textbf{1,1}$,$0$) |
| W | ($\textbf{1,3}$,$0$) |
| G | ($\textbf{8,1}$,$0$) |

Now I understand that for instance the W field exists in the $\textbf{3}$ representation of $SU(2)_{L}$ which is where we get the 3 $W$ bosons of weak isospin ($W_{1}$,$W_{2}$,$W_{3}$), but in the $\textbf{1}$ of $SU(3)_{C}$ which means the W boson transforms under the trivial representation and therefore does not carry color charge. I am comfortable with that, but what does it mean that all 3 vector boson fields, including the $\textbf{B}$ field itself, exist in the $0$ of $U(1)_{Y}$? I naively expected them to all exist in the $\textbf{1}$ representation, which I understand to be the trivial representation. If my question is too open ended, then perhaps I can ask it as: What is the difference between a field existing the in the $\textbf{1}$ representation of a U(1) group, versus the $0$ representation of that same group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a notational issue - for non-Abelian groups, we often label their representations by their dimension $n$ as $\mathbf{n}$. For the Abelian $\mathrm{U}(1)$, all representations are one-dimensional, so that labeling doesn't make sense, and one usually instead labels the representation by the integer $k$ in the representation map $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi}\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k\phi}$, and for the trivial representation $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi}\mapsto 1$, this is $k=0$.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense then. So in essence, the difference is really just what you call the "trivial" representation wr.t. each gauge group? For instance, for the non-abelian $SU(2)$ we refer to $\textbf{1}$ as being the trivial, but for abelian $U(1)$ we refer to $0$ as being the trivial?